# Visual Studio, Hundreds of bogus error messages, all on line 1 of apsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 14.0.24720.00 Update 1, I have a solution with a single ASP.NET C# project. When I try to compile, I get 281 errors, all on line 1.  This happens frequently, sometimes with close to 1,000 errors, but in the past there has always been at least one actual error somewhere in the list, identifiable by a line number other than 1, and when it was removed all the other messages would go away too.  (Sometimes I had to re-compile twice.)  In this case, all 281 error are supposedly on line 1, and none of them seem to be valid errors.

Here are the first 4 lines of the .ASPX file:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PrintRaces.aspx.cs" Inherits="iVoterGuide.com.Print.PrintRaces" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

And here is a sample of the error messages, chosen because this section has more different messages than most:
[image: Some error messages]

The first few errors are all 'Newline in constant,' 'Too many characters in character literal,' or 'Empty character literal.'  I cannot find any character literals in my code.  From memory of other instances, I think there are the three most frequent messages and they usually head the list.

In this case, the file is a newly created .ASPX file with C# code-behind.  There is no master page and I removed all scripts, CSS, and includes, with no change in the result.

Can someone suggest a cause or way of diagnosing the problem?  Thanks so much.

EDIT: It seems clear that some VB code is accidentally being compiled by the c# compiler, but where does it come from and why do the errors go away when errors are removed from the c# code?

Comment: I think you have defined the same variable twice.  The 1st line says it all "already contains a definition for Get".

Comment: The real reason all errors appear in line 1 is there is no returns on any of the lines.  Adding a return on each line will give you the exact line number where the error is occurring.

Comment: Seems you are trying to mix and match VB.NET and C# syntax - you cannot do that. you can only stick to C# or VB.NET.

Comment: I agree that the VB code has not line numbers, but since I don't know where it comes from, I cannot fix it.  Also, the filename given is the .aspx file and line 1 contains only the '<%@ Page...' directive.  If some VB code is included on line 1, even implicitly, then it makes sense, but were does it come from?

Comment: I'm voting to close (and ultimately delete) this question as it was a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

All the error messages point to the fact that you have VB code when it is expecting C#. `As` and `End` are VB keywords while your ASPX page says it's C# and the code behind file is a .cs file which is a C# file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this really counts as an answer, but the problem is gone. There was a missing } at the end of the c# file.  When I fixed that, all the messages went away.

Comment: Yeah, that counts as an answer. When the compiler has a spectacular nervous breakdown like that, a missing brave or paren is often the culprit.